# Reference on how to write my own RDP client

Tags: rdp

I want to be able to access some device specific data while running an application on a remote machine. The problem is that if the RDP window is minimized this data is not available. One solution I'm examining is writing my own RDP client so that the server machine always thinks that it has an active display (even when the client machine is locked).

Does anyone know of a reference on how to develop an RDP client (preferably in .NET)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26620484/1733117

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Terminals](http://www.codeplex.com/Terminals) at Codeplex.  Open source multiple RDP client; browse the code for some hints.

Comment: Project Terminals seems to have been shutdown.