# RDP library for Android

Tags: android, rdp

I am trying to develop an android version of Remote Desktop Sharing (Remote PhoneTop Sharing) to share some files or applications in real-time.

I am trying to implement this by using **Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP)**.  Is there any RDP libraries available for Android?

I checked **Proper Java**, but it seems like it is for Java and we may need to make lot of code changes to make it work for Android.

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26620484/1733117

Comment: What did you end up using?

Answer (score 0):

You could give [connectoid](http://code.google.com/p/connectoid/) a shot.

Comment: I don't think that Connectoid is a library. It is a RDP client for android.